# Who’s dragging Elend down here?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn

In a charming broadsheet issued around the time of *The Alloy of Law*, one can find an advertisement for an opera apparently based on Vin and Elend’s adventures.

[image]

They seem to have reimagined it as an epic romance.

Now, Vin’s being dragged down by Inquisitors, obviously (see the spikes?). That, at least, is historically accurate, though strangely they're shirtless. But who are those people dragging down Elend?

Comment: Maybe by Skaa or his subordinates? Or they are "the embodiment" of the Empire.

Comment: Inquisitors, actually. Spikes thru eyes.

Comment: @Radhil - I doubt they’re Inquisitors. Did Inquisitors normally go shirtless? Then again, this isn’t the most historically accurate play.

Comment: @Adamant - Of course they do.  How else would you be able to see all the spikes?.... this is *advertising*.  It's their job to lie.

Comment: @Radhil - It’s true, they have the Inquisitor spike pattern (or close to it; I doubt any playwright in modern-day Mistborn knows enough to *really* get it right).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They almost certainly look like humans, with the one on the bottom left looking like a noble, whereas the one directly beneath him with the eyepatch looks like a skaa.

The rest are difficult to place specifically other than being human, as they do not look they would be Koloss or Inquisitors. Some look more destitute than others, so they are likely made up of both skaa and nobility. I suppose they could be Kandra disguised as humans, but it's unlikely.

Overall, I would say they are simply the **citizens of Luthadel**.

Throughout the Well of Ascension book, Vin focused mainly on the task of fighting the Koloss and the invading armies, whilst Elend focused on the politics of making sure the city wasn't attacked in the first place.

Throughout the events of Hero Of Ages, they had more of an equal role, but it was Vin who fought the Inquisitors single-handed. Elend very rarely used his powers as a mistborn except when he was only with Vin, or on his own. When he did, he was already renowned as the leader of Luthadel, and later Emperor.

So it is probable that is how their legacy survived after the ascension. The picture likely represents the respective greatest challenges that they faced as individuals that kept them from being together.

Elend fought his battles with words, and is depicted as having to deal with both the nobility and skaa of Luthadel. Vin fought her battles with allomancy, and would be remembered for having fought both Koloss and Inquisitors.

Comment: Yep they appear to be humans and I think the OP has misinterpreted it as they don't appear to be "dragging him down" especially. It actually looks more like some are pleading for his help and others are cheering/celebrating.